# How to convert SQL Date to String in Java?

Tags: java, android, mysql

So I'm building a simple app which shows a list of dates in a ListView.
The dates are being fetched from a database in JSON format.

My database has a column 'AttendanceDate' of 'date' data type.

I think the problem is with 'date' data type of SQL. If so, how do I convert the date ( in 'date') to date ( in 'String').

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
jsonObject.getString("AttendanceDate").toString();
```

I also tried to typecast the date to string but that too didn't work:

```
String date = (String) jsonObject.get("AttemdanceDate");
```

Link to Json string: http://sasananshul.16mb.com/test.php

Comment: "I tried this but it didn't work: jsonObject.getString("AttendanceDate").toString();" That will certainly have given you a `String` (provided `getString` didn't return `null`); what was it about this string which wasn't right for your requirements?

Comment: Beside what @AndyTurner said, use `SimpleDateFormat` to format a `Date` to a `String` in the correct format.

Comment: But how do i pass the date( from JSON) to SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: you have to do something like this . String date=response.getJsonobject(0).getJsonArray("attendance").get(0).getString("AttemdanceDate"); .. This will get you the date which is already given you in string format

Comment: look like you need to visit this link [Convert String to Date](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Below I have given a code snippet that could help you to change the Date to String format.

```
    //Creating Date in java with today's date.
    Date dateNow = new Date();

    //change date into string yyyyMMdd format example "20110914"
    SimpleDateFormat dateformatyyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String date_to_string = dateformatyyyyMMdd.format(dateNow);
    System.out.println("date into yyyyMMdd format: " + date_to_string);
```